# How to convert MIME type to preferred filename extension on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

I have a MIME type: audio/x-wav

I want the preferred filename extension: .wav

Is there a way to obtain this information on iOS?

I have tried...

```
CFStringRef uttype = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, @"audio/x-wav", NULL);
CFStringRef utpt = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uttype, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);
```

...but the value of 'uttype' returned is prefixed with "dyn" (indicates type-not-found according to the docs) and 'utpt' is therefore NULL.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, a UTI prefixed with `dyn` means that the UTI was hitherto unknown to the system and created a new, "dynamic" UTI because you asked it for information about a MIME type.  Since the MIME type is unknown to the system, it obviously doesn't know what file extensions have the MIME type.

Comment: So I guess the UTI stuff is a no-go.  Is there another API that I can try?  Thanks!